# How to randomly select from a list of rows excluding rows with certain values in adjacent column

Tags: random, google-sheets, excel-formula, formulas, gs-vlookup

I am trying to make a random generator which picks random cards from a list of cards (from a game) but I would like to have the ability to enter a few parameters to filter out certain subsets of cards. Lets say every card has 2 types of subset, a `<Rarity>` and `<Colour>`.

So far I set up my generator to work with a formula on `Google Sheets` as follows:

```
     A         B         C            D             E          F         G
1  Card    <Rarity>   <Colour>  <Filter Rarity>    Card    <Rarity>   <Colour>
===============================================================================
2  Blah1    Common     Blue           X              <Generator formulas>
3  Blah2    Common     Red            X              <Generator formulas>
4  Blah3    Uncommon   White          X              <Generator formulas>
5  Blah4    Legendary  Green          X              <Generator formulas>
```

On the left most three columns are the cards with their respective details. The `D` column was the one I was trying to enter all the `<Rarity>` values I would like my formula to ignore when randomly picking from the A,B,C columns.

The code in the E,F,G columns are as follows:

```
E
=INDEX($A$2:$A$537,LARGE(MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$537),ROW($A$2:$A$537))*NOT(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$537)),RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS($A$2:$A$537)-ROW(A1)+1)))

F and G just vlookups to return the values in columns B and C.
=vlookup(E2,$A$2:$C$760,2,FALSE)
```

I pieced this formula together from other formulas I had done previously so I had to go back and try to figure out how to enter a condition that if any of the cards in `A` have a value in `B` that matches one listed in `D` then they should not be picked. But I am not sure where best to put it or how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

`=QUERY(FILTER({A2:C537,RANDBETWEEN(SIGN(ROW(A2:A537)),1E+308)},ISNA(MATCH(B2:B537,D2:D,0))),"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' order by Col4 limit 10",0)`

This appends a column of random numbers, filters out the ones that don't appear in column D, sorts the first 3 columns based on the column of random numbers, and "limit 10" allows you to specify how many cards you want randomly selected.

Comment: First of all thank you for your time. I did not know google sheets could integrate the Google API language into the querry! That seems like a superbly versatile thing to learn! Is it possible to integrate into the filtering also variables from column C if they are written into Column D? As in if I write both colours and rarities in columnd D that I wish to filter out?

Comment: Ah I worked it out, I simply added another `ISNA(MATCH(C2:C537,D2:D,0))` into the filter conditions. That was surprisingly straight forwards. Thank you ever so much for your knowledge!

Comment: This solution works, however it seems that if too many variables are used as exclusions, then the list the query returns is broken and returns an inferior number of entries than the limit. So for example I am not able to filter out all colours except 1 and have it return more than 19 entries despite there being several hundred entries available. IS it maybe only cycling through the list once and picking out too few?

Comment: Ah actually the issue was that I also applied the formula to a list much larger than 537, 779 entries in fact and it worked. Thanks again.